# Plotting of 3d vector equation

Tags: calculus, vectors

Suppose $r=\langle t^3+4t,t,2t^2\rangle$ is a vector function.

I want to find which curve has the following parametrization

$x=t^3+4t$,
$y=t$,
$z=2t^2$

$x=\frac{yz}{2}+4y$ (**Is it Correct?**)

even if my parametrization is not correct above equation will represent a surface but vector function $r$ is a curve traced out by the head of $r$ not a surface.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: $z$ and $y$ are not independent quantities in $x=\frac{yz}{2}+4y$, because $z=2y^2$. So your line is intersection of two surfaces $x=\frac{yz}{2}+4y$ and $z=2y^2$.

Comment: @Ivan Kaznacheyeu How line is the intersection of those surfaces.

Comment: The easiest two equations to use are $$z=2y^2\\x=y^3+4y$$

Comment: @user1055 I mean curve, not straight line.